# How to press (or send key) Enter or Backspace in Appium

Tags: appium, appium-ios, appium-android

In Android, you can send key code which Android has supported for Android already ([for references](http://%20https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html))

But in iOS, no document describes that how to press Enter and Backspace in iOS (XCTest).

I accidentally figure out how to do that, so I made this ticket to help you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can send below specified letter:

`sendKeys('\n')` for press ***Enter***

and

`sendKeys('\b')` for press ***Backspace***

Update: Test on Appium version 7.1, it does not work on Android. Use this way to type Enter, Next, Go key.

https://appium.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/writing-running-appium/android/android-ime/

Reference more [sendKeys API](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/actions/send-keys/index.html) in other programming languages